JSON data to database, mapping Json with field contains array[string], transform to string
I use this code to record JSON data to an Oracle database.
SELECT NOM, PRENOMS, DATE_NAISS
    FROM JSON_TABLE('[
        {
            "Id": 123,
            "Nom": "Toto",
            "Prenoms": [
                "Pascal",
                "Vincent"
            ],
            "DateNaissance": "1983-01-01T00:00:00"
        }]', '$[*]' COLUMNS 
             (
               "NOM"        PATH '$.Nom',
               "PRENOMS"    PATH '$.Prenoms',
               "DATE_NAISS" DATE PATH  '$.DateNaissance'
             ) ) T_JSON;

I want to concat the elements of field "Prenoms" like this
[ {
    "Id": 123,
    "Nom": "Toto",
    "Prenoms": "Pascal, Vincent",
    "DateNaissance": "1983-01-01T00:00:00",
} ]

Could you help me, please?
Thanks
This is the code I tried, but it's not ok, it returns an empty string:
"PRENOMS" varchar2(100) FORMAT JSON PATH '$."Prenoms"[*]'


Extract the prenoms array as an array and then split it separately and then aggregate it into your desired format:
SELECT NOM,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG(prenom, ', ')
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  PRENOMS,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS (prenom VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$')
                )
       ) AS prenoms,
       DATE_NAISS
FROM   JSON_TABLE('[
  {
    "Id": 123,
    "Nom": "Toto",
    "Prenoms": [ "Pascal", "Vincent" ],
    "DateNaissance": "1983-01-01T00:00:00"
  }
]',
        '$[*]'
        COLUMNS (
          "NOM"        VARCHAR2(200)    PATH '$.Nom',
          "PRENOMS"    CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.Prenoms',
          "DATE_NAISS" DATE             PATH  '$.DateNaissance'
        )
      );

Which outputs:



NOM
PRENOMS
DATE_NAISS




Toto
Pascal, Vincent
1983-01-01 00:00:00



If you want it back in JSON format then:
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
         JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'Id' VALUE ID,
           KEY 'Nom' VALUE NOM,
           KEY 'Prenoms' VALUE (
             SELECT LISTAGG(prenom, ', ')
             FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                      PRENOMS,
                      '$[*]'
                      COLUMNS (prenom VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$')
                    )
           ),
           KEY 'DateNaissance' VALUE DATE_NAISS
         )
       ) AS json
FROM   JSON_TABLE('[
  {
    "Id": 123,
    "Nom": "Toto",
    "Prenoms": [ "Pascal", "Vincent" ],
    "DateNaissance": "1983-01-01T00:00:00"
  }
]',
        '$[*]'
        COLUMNS (
          ID         NUMBER           PATH '$.Id',
          NOM        VARCHAR2(200)    PATH '$.Nom',
          PRENOMS    CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$.Prenoms',
          DATE_NAISS DATE             PATH '$.DateNaissance'
        )
      );

Which outputs:



JSON




[{"Id":123,"Nom":"Toto","Prenoms":"Pascal, Vincent","DateNaissance":"1983-01-01T00:00:00"}]



fiddle

You can also do it using nested path:
        '$[*]' COLUMNS 
         (
            id  PATH '$.Id',
           NOM        PATH '$.Nom',
           DATE_NAISS DATE PATH  '$.DateNaissance',
           nested path '$.Prenoms[*]'
           columns (
            ord for ordinality,
            PRENOM    PATH '$'
           )
         ) 

and then
listagg(PRENOM, ', ') within group(order by ord) as prenoms

